# Failing to import properties of a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a module A that is like

```
const defaults = {
   something: {...},
   somethingElse : {...}
}

export { defaults as default };
```

And then I am importing like

```
import * as mod, { something } from 'moduleA';
```

`mod` is correctly an object that has the two declared properties, but `{ something }` is undefined.

Any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: @nils Why would you say that is invalid? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @torazaburo you are right, I was mistaken, I was confusing it with the new syntax outlined in this proposal: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [With the module as in the question] I am importing like
>
> ```
> import * as mod, { something } from 'moduleA';
> ```
>
> but `something` is undefined

But you don't have an export with the name `something` in your module. There only is a default-export that contains an object. You would need to do

```
import mod from 'moduleA';
const { something } = mod;
```

> I have a module A that is like
>
> ```
> const defaults = {
>    something: {...},
>    somethingElse : {...}
> }
>
> export { defaults as default };
> ```

But you really shouldn't do that anyway. Exporting "singleton" objects that act like a namespace is an antipattern in ES6 modules. You should use named exports instead:

```
export const something = {...};
export const somethingElse = {...};
```

With this, your original attempt at importing the module would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access named exports in your import, you have to export them directly:

```
const defaults = {
   something: {...},
   somethingElse : {...}
}

export {
    defaults as default,
    defaults.something as something,
    defaults.somethingElse as somethingElse
};
```

Alternatively you could use destructuring for the export of `something` and `somethingElse`:

```
export const { something, somethingElse} = defaults;
```

And then import it like you did:

```
import * as mod, { something } from 'moduleA';
```

But: mod will now contain the props: `defaults, something, somethingElse`.

If you only wont the `default` (which equals your `defaults`):

```
import mod, { something } from 'moduleA';
```

You can learn more about the ES6 import and export syntax in Axel Rauschmayr's great blog post:

http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: `export const {something, somethingElse} = defaults;` doesnt seem to be valid

Comment: @AvraamMavridis: Why? Seems to be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Bergi is this valid? I wasn't sure and I didn't have the time to setup a test case.

Comment: @nils: I was surprised a bit at first because I haven't seen the pattern before, but from how I understand the spec it's completely legit.

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as mod, { something } from 'moduleA';
```

The reason something is undefined is because when you: `export { defaults as default };`  you're exporting a member called default.  When you `export {apple, banana}` you export a member `apple` and a member `banana`.

When you import something without specifying the members you want to import you import the member named default.  When you do specify the members you wish to import, of course, you import those.

This is why although your code doesn't do what you intend, the following will:

```
const mod = { something: 'test'};
export { mod as default }; // same as export default mod;
```

and

```
import mod, {default as test} from './index'; // test and mod both have the same values

console.log(mod); // { something: 'test' }
console.log(test.something); // test
```

Answer (score -2):

`something` is not exported from your module A, only the object `defaults` is.

So, to get `something`, you need to take it from what you imported.

```
import * as mod from 'moduleA';

const something = mod.something;
```

If you want to be able to import `something` like this : `import {something} from 'moduleA'`, you will need to export it explicitely. For example:

```
export const something = {};
const somethingElse = {};

export default const defaults = {
  something,
  somethingElse
};
```

Comment: you dont have to export something explicitly to import it if it is part of an exported object, you could use deconstruction.